# Hosting Openfire on Openshift

Tags: xmpp, openshift, openfire

1. Can I deploy Openfire on Openshift?
2. Will it work?
3. Can I deploy other xmpp server?
4. Before Openfire was on VPS, but now I need make it via Openshift, Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I also want to deploy Openfire on a remote server, any helpful link or answer would be really appreciated.